# What can one now do with the Aquarus b10 Ubuntu tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Or did I purchase yet another electronic paperweight?

Answer (score 2):

If by "Aquarus b10" you mean the *BQ Aquaris M10* then it's supported by [UBports](https://ubports.com/), a fork of Ubuntu Phone.